# Alien-friendly decontamination

Tags: biology

I'm working on a story that I like to describe as a more hard sci-fi version of Star Trek, set about 150-300 years from now. The human faction cares a great deal about the welfare of alien life, and as such, they have to ensure that their suits, equipment, etc. aren't going to harm the local environment, or worse. How would it be possible to not only remove any hostile pathogens, but also avoid introducing unwelcome chemicals, in a short amount of time? For the sake of my mental wellbeing, the main aliens in the story are carbon-based, drink water, and breathe oxygen.

EDIT: the humans have crash-landed on an entirely unknown world, hence the need for urgency. I should have mentioned this before.

Comment: Ultraviolets work wonders when it comes to killing microorganisms. (And I don't understand what you mean by introducing unwelcome chemicals. Surely the spacesuits are made to be as chemically inert as human ingenuity can make them and not shed sulfuric acid or such stuff.)

Comment: I meant something like isopropyl alcohol, which current technology uses for sterilising probes. I admit I'm a little more versed in astrophysics and the basics of evolution than chemistry...

Comment: I am absolutely sure that no isopropyl alcohol is left on the surface of the probes when they are integrated with the launch vehicle. The nice thing about Isopropyl alcohol is that is evaporates very quickly and leaves no residue. This is why it is commonly used as a hand sanitizer and as a cleaner for delicate stuff that admits being cleaned with alcohol. Even if they use Isopropyl alcohol to sterilize their suits (which is silly, why use a consumable when UV light can be made on demand), I do not see any easy way to *prevent* the alcohol from evaporating so as to be carried outside.

Comment: So UV is the way to go, then? How long would it take?

Comment: The time required to sterilize a surface depends on the intensity of the UV light, and how thorough the sterilization is intended to be. (And vice-versa, if shorter time is needed, a stronger UV source will be required.) Typical dosage is between 2,000 and 10,000 μW·s/cm².

Comment: Thanks for all this. I imagine a higher dose should be fine since the wearer's going to be in a fully sealed suit...

Comment: As long as you dont point it at theyr eyes or they close them shut, they should retain vision aswell.

Comment: Fire generally works for any microorganisms. Make the suits fireproof and insulated (for the safety of the humans anyway), and bathe them in fire for a minute as a decontamination step before they exit the vehicle. That could an airlock as well, for in space operations, it should all be sterilized, you shouldn't be letting any alien microbes in your ship. Also, if this is Star Trek, just program the transporter to not transport any foreign microbes or chemicals that don't belong there on the outside of the hazmat suit, either incoming or outgoing transporter operations.

Comment: @Amadeus It's LIKE Star Trek, in that it's meant to be an optimistic portrayal of the near future. I aim to keep things scientifically plausible (for a near-future setting), for the most part, so no transporters.

Answer (score 3):

Don't send humans to interact with aliens until both humans and the relevant species have both made sure their germs won't harm each other. This might involve lab conditions, volunteers and years of research.

Until then, send drones - either remotely controlled, or smart enough to be autonomous. You can decontaminate the drones with chemicals and radiation.

Or better yet - just use radio from a safe distance.

OP put in this edit:

> EDIT: the humans have crash-landed on an entirely unknown world, hence the need for urgency. I should have mentioned this before.

Best effort then. Put on a hazmat or space suit and scrub yourself with cleanex/lysol, or shower in bleach, or whatever cleaning stuff the aliens have. Come back inside the wreck whenever you need to take of the suit.

Comment: I should have mentioned that this is a crash-landing upon an entirely unknown world -- they don't really have a lot of time...